# Is it possible to hide whole wordpress site for desktop?

Tags: android, css, wordpress

i want to hide my whole word press site for desktops, so it only shows for mobile and tablet, is that possible?

second question not so important though: is it possible to show website only for android devices?

warm regards K.M

Comment: develop an App for android instead of wordpress site. I guess the issue here is that you are choosing the wrong tool.

Comment: i understand but my question was actually if it was possible to hide with wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Wordpress plugins like **WPBakery** or **Widget Context** to hide content on specific devices.

Answer (score 0):

You could add this script:

```
<script>
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var Android = userAgent.indexOf("android") > -1; 
if (!Android) {
 document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.innerHTML = 'Please use an Android device';
}
</script>
```

This example runs the code when the button is clicked:

```js
function isAndroid() {
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(); 
var Android = userAgent.indexOf("android") > -1; 
if (!Android) {
 document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = "Please use an Android device";
}
}
```

```html
<body>
<h2>Your beautiful Wordpress site</h2>
<p>This is a Wordpress site</p>
<button onClick="isAndroid()">Check if Android</button>
</body>
```

Comment: fantastic :) as i ma novice with coding what code do i use as you add two?

do i add this one in the header?

 `<script>
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var Android = userAgent.indexOf("android") > -1; 
if (!Android) {
 document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.innerHTML = 'Please use an Android device';
}
</script>`

and this code were do i add it?

`function isAndroid() {
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(); 
var Android = userAgent.indexOf("android") > -1; 
............`

Comment: hello mr_shazbot,

i tried your code in a normal html page and still showing the page in desktop view i added the script and button inside body tags and did not work. what am i doing wrong?